# why using std::sqrt failed if I redefine the sqrt function?

Tags: c++, function, namespaces, std, redefine

```
#include<iostream>

double sqrt(double);

int main()
{
    double a = std::sqrt(4.0);
    std::cout << a; 
    return 0;
}

double sqrt(double a)
{
    return 1.0;
}
```

I know I declare the sqrt at first, but I use std::sqrt, it still call my own sqrt. why?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is this your *actual* code? What compiler/platform?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2019 on Windows: clang-cl compiles without warning and gives an output of `2` (i.e. `std::sqrt` is called). However, the MSVC compiler doesn't like it: **error C2169: 'sqrt': intrinsic function, cannot be defined**.

Comment: The problem is reproducible using MSVC.

Comment: @AdrianMole  https://rextester.com/CMIEE93010

Comment: @AdrianMole, in my local VS 2019 using MSVC the result is also 1.

Comment: Maybe you have intrinsic functions disabled. But anyway, it's undefined behaviour (see dupe).

Comment: I use VS 2019 and platform is Windows, I do not know how to check the compiler. it is no error on my computer, but has C28251 warning, the result on my computer is 1.

Comment: Is it possible because you didn't include a math header?

Answer (score 0):

Search your code for a `using namespace std;` somewhere. Perhaps hidden in some other set of include files.

Comment: Adding `using namespace std;` to the OP's code makes no difference to clang-cl and MSVC! Same results as in my comment to the question.

Comment: OP's code is **undefined behaviour** (see suggested duplicate).